# How to connect to Bedrock Server on Windows from WAN side?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

My setup works fine on my LAN, and an [online port checker](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) says that my Minecraft server port is OPEN to the Internet.

- Windows 10, with Minecraft bedrock server version = `1.18.1.02`
- The server has `whitelist=false` so any outside users *should* be welcome to join.
- Minecraft players outside my LAN can see my server, including ping = 16ms.
  => This proves that my server is indeed responding, and my LAN port forwarding* is working!
- But when these outside players then try to actually CONNECT to my world, THEN they get the message that they cannot connect.
- The Minecraft server output correctly shows LAN activity but  does not show anything at all about any outside connection attempts.

**--> What do I need to do to make outside players connect to my world?**

---

*Update:* I just spent half a night installing Docker for Windows so that I could run the Bedrock server as a Docker container, and this too is not reachable from outside.

---

*My LAN port forwarding:

- DSL modem is *wide open*, forwards everything to my gateway.
- Gateway has explicit rule to forward the 4 minecraft ports to the LAN IP of my local server.
- ports as reported by the Minecraft server output are 19132,19133,25565,59989.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I had the same issue running a bedrock server from a docker container on my synology NAS.

The solution is to connect from the outside, it does not work if you try to connect from your LAN to the WAN Port.